# Why Do I Get "undefined" After Few Iterations?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

A strange thing happens with my code below. The code runs smoothly with only one exception - after few iterations, I get "undefined".

You can test it by running it few times. At first, you will get regular output (three random cities) and then at some point you will get "undefined". That happens in less than 10 iterations.

Why does it do it? What am I missing?

```js
var coolWords = ["Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Sofia", "Prague", "Lisbon", "London", "Malaga", "Copenhagen", "Milan"];
    
var newList = [];
    
function niceTripleCombo(coolWords) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var combo = coolWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*coolWords.length)];
    newList.push(" " + combo);
  };
};
    
function iterator(x) {
  if (newList[0] !== newList[1] && newList[1] !== newList[2] && newList[1] !== newList[3]) {
    return newList;
  } else {
    return niceTripleCombo(coolWords);
  }
};
    
    console.log(iterator(niceTripleCombo(coolWords)));
```

Comment: Don't you need to minus one from `coolWords.length` as its not zero indexed?

Comment: A call to `niceTripleCombo(coolWords)` does not `return` anything. So why are you passing that in to `iterator()` (as `x`) and try to `return` it from `iterator`?

Comment: @ste2425 no. `Math.floor` takes care of that.

Comment: You return the result of `nuceTripleCombo`, but that doesn't return anything, so you get `undefined`.

Comment: You are also not iterating here until you get the desired result, you are just returning. So maybe you should consider a) A way to empty your newList or simply not store it globally, B) a way to keep asking for a list with new words. This isn't good either, this _could_ keep going forever, so maybe it's best to remove the words from your original list when picking them so you _know_ they will be unique.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I see what you mean but how do you call a function inside another function then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets consider this test run.

Initiatelly, `iterator(niceTripleCombo(coolWords))` is called from `console.log()`.

Now `niceTripleCombo(coolWords)` will be called.

**Start of niceTripleCombo(coolWords)**

Now in for loop,

i = 0, suppose we get `newList = [" Milan"]`

i = 1, suppose we get `newList = [" Milan", " London"]`

i = 2, suppose we get `newList =  [" Milan", " London", " London"]`

**End of niceTripleCombo(coolWords)**

At the end we have **Milan, London, London**

Now in `iterator()`,

Since we have 2 london, `if` will fail and `else` will be run.

**Now here is 1st mistake**, you didn't initialize the `newList` to empty. So when `niceTripleCombo` is run again, it will add three more cities.

And you might get, for example, `[" Milan", " London", " London", " Amsterdam", " Malaga", " Sofia"]`

**Now secondly**, `return niceTripleCombo(coolWords);` won't return any value.

Why it wont return anything is because, you are returning a function[`niceTripleCombo(coolWords)`] which doesn't have a return statement.

> Either your function must **return any value** or if returning a
>   function, that function must return a value. In your case,
>   you don't have a **return statement** in `niceTripleCombo(coolWords)`
>   and by default a js function returns `undefined` if no other value is
>   returned.

That is why you are getting `undefined`.

So, change your `else` in your `iterator` to like this:

```
else {
  newList = [];
  niceTripleCombo(coolWords);
  return iterator();
}
```

Now you shouldn't get `undefined`. Next, there is no need to pass the `niceTripleCombo` to `iterator`. Since you are not using the `niceTripleCombo` function inside you `iterator`.

Read more about `return` in MDN: [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 0):

When your newList Array has following values,

```
 [" Berlin", " Berlin", " London"]
```

or similar where one of array element is same, your if condition in iterator fails, and you are executing

```
niceTripleCombo(coolWords)
```

which has no return value , Hence returns undefined.

Comment: Hi @sridhar! Thanks for your answer! I am not sure the `newList` can produce a duplicate of a word already selected, never seen this happening. What do you mean by `niceTripleCombo(coolWords)` has no return value? Can you explain, pls? Thanks!

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random()*coolWords.length) . , It can generate any number between 0 and coolWords.length and they can be same some times.

Comment: function niceTripleCombo(coolWords) has no return statement inside, If there is no return statement , Then it returns as undefined.Like in iterator , you have explicitly return keyword , but in niceTripleCombo no return statement is there

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`newList` array should be returned inside `niceTripleCombo` method.

```js
var coolWords = ["Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Sofia", "Prague", "Lisbon", "London", "Malaga", "Copenhagen", "Milan"];

var newList = [];

function niceTripleCombo(coolWords) {
  newList.length = 0; // Empty the array before starting
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var combo = coolWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*coolWords.length)];
    newList.push(" " + combo);
  };
  return newList; //Returning an array.
};

function iterator(x) {
  if (newList[0] !== newList[1] && newList[1] !== newList[2] && newList[1] !== newList[3]) {
    return newList;
  } else {
    return niceTripleCombo(coolWords);
  }
};

console.log(iterator(niceTripleCombo(coolWords)));
```

Comment: Hi @Kumar and thanks for the answer! What is the reason for the `newList` to be returned inside `niceTripleCombo`? Isn't it the same when returning it from inside the `iterator`?

Comment: A function returns `undefined` by default unless specified otherwise. Since in your case you expect `niceTripleCombo` to return you an array, you need to specify that. Please note you're not returning anything from inside the `iterator`. You only pushing items into it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes on your code:

- You are *not* iterating over amnything, you are just checking once
- If the outcome is to get a unique trio of words, this method is going to waste a lot of cycles if the randomiser doesn't give you the right numbers.
- If you are passing an array around, why make it a global variable? This will make your iterator pointless.
- You guessing function has no return value - so it returns `undefined`.

My suggestion would be this:

```js
var coolWords = ["Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Sofia", "Prague", "Lisbon", "London", "Malaga", "Copenhagen", "Milan"];

function niceTripleCombo( list ) {

  // Make a copy of the list so we don't modify the original.
  let words = list.slice();
  let result = [];
  
  for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    
    // Use splice to get a word out of your copy array
    // It also removes it from the array,
    // so next time we cannot guess this word anymore.
    result.push(
      words.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * words.length ), 1 )[ 0 ]
    );
    
  }
  
  return result;
  
};

console.log( niceTripleCombo(coolWords) );
```

This will always return a list of three unique words, and it does it by picking a random word from the array, removing it from the array and adding it to the answer, and then repeating with the now shorter array. That way you only need to run this cycle *three* times instead of the possibly infinite amount if the randomiser isn't on your side.

Comment: Hi @somethinghere!  Thanks a lot for your answer, it's very detailed. Few things come to mind: 1) why do you say the code is not iterating but only checking once? Can you explain, pls? 2) About the global variable - couldn't make my code run when it was inside the first function. 3) How does the guessing function "doesn't have a return value"? I don't get it. Hope you will enlighten me! I am eager to learn more so I can become a real developer. Cheers!

Comment: 1) You call `iterator` once, do a check and return eithre the value or one more `try`, after that you stop. You would need to call `iterator` again inside your `iterator` to keep going until the desired outcome is reached. 2) You need to learn about `return`ing correctly, then you pass variables around without a global object. 3) The function that guesses has no `return` statement, so it is not returning a value. You global value isd also not reset, so `[0]`,`[1]` and `[2]` will always remain the same, so once incorrect then your outcome will always be incorrect.

Comment: hey @somethinghere, thanks a lot! I will try to dive deeper into what you and the rest are saying and improve.

Comment: looking at your code now and comparing with the MDN definition - why did you put zero in-between brackets after the splice arguments, @somethinghere? I couldn't see that anywhere in the MDN specification.

Comment: @tonkatata The return value of splice: _'An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.'_. Since we want an array of strings to be returned in the end and not an array of arrays with single elements each we need to extract the first element of them using `[0]`. We could also use `pop()` or `shift()` to accomplish the same thing. By doing this we can `push` the returned string directly into our `result` array.

Comment: oh dude, after thinking about it for 20min I got it! :D without `[0]` each iteration will return an array with only one string and then will `push` each of these arrays into the `result` array. but by using `[0]` each `push` appends only the string into the `result` array. @somethinghere

Comment: @tonkatata Jup, it's the difference between `[string, string, string]` and `[[string],[string],[string]]`! It's therefor very important to read about what a function returns, since that becomes the variable you need to work with next.

Comment: very well put! Thank you!